# Drupal: adding disclaimer text above the submit button in a webform

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-fapi, drupal-alter

Is there an easy-ish way to modify the webform-form-tpl.php template to show disclaimer text above the submit button in a Drupal webform? I can add text below the button, but do not know how to split up the button from the other elements to add text between them, ie:

```
[form-elements]
[disclaimer text]
[submit button]
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option is probably is insert the text as a markup form item using [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) on the form.

Comment: That way, you could even create a checkbox which sumbittants have to check (sth. like "I've read T&C.").

Comment: The text could be added to the submit button's '#prefix' property. If you add a checkbox instead, make it required, so people can't submit the form if the box isn't checked.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me :

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#prefix'] = 'Disclaimer...';
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really belong in the theme layer; it's content. You can add the disclaimer as a markup component to the end of the webform and it should appear after the other webform components and before the submit button like you want.